# Viewport shading - Random, Single Color not working

Tags: 3d-view, color

when I change the settings in Viewport to random or single color, nothing happens. But when I add the material manually and choose the color for 3d viewport in the settings, everything works. Did I miss something in the general settings, or do you know what could be causing this?

Thank you so much for the suggestions!

[image: single color]

[image: random color]

Here's the link of .blend file:

[image]

Comment: You're doing the right things, as far as I can tell, so it looks like you've hit a bug.  can you share that blend file so others can see if they can reproduce the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Alright! File added :-) @MartyFouts

Comment: Your file works fine here both in Single or Random colour mode. (Blender 3.0 under Windows 10).

Comment: Hm, interesting...I'm on Arch Linux 5.15, Blender 3.0 as well

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I have discovered the cause of the problem - old hardware and unsupported graphics drivers. More here:

https://developer.blender.org/T80887

Comment: Ah! I was going to suggest that. Unfortunately I only have Linux running in a VM under Windows here which wouldn't have tested graphics drivers as it would presumably be using the Windows or VM ones.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that on blender 2.91 (but also 3.1) on windows the objects are in random color using the setting you are testing:

[image]